# What's the expect outcome for `alert`?

Tags: elisp

I try to use `alert` and copy the example from [here](https://github.com/jwiegley/alert) as below:

*scratch* buffer:

```
(require 'alert)

;; This is the most basic form usage
(alert "This is an alert")

;; You can adjust the severity for more important messages
(alert "This is an alert" :severity 'high)

;; Or decrease it for purely informative ones
(alert "This is an alert" :severity 'trivial)

;; Alerts can have optional titles.  Otherwise, the title is the
;; buffer-name of the (current-buffer) where the alert originated.
(alert "This is an alert" :title "My Alert")

;; Further, alerts can have categories.  This allows users to
;; selectively filter on them.
(alert "This is an alert" :title "My Alert" :category 'debug)
```

After `eval-buffer`, it seems nothing happens.

I am not sure what should I expect after evaluate the `alert` function?

Comment: Have you read the help page for alert (`C-h f alert`)?

Comment: Isn't it almost the same as what I have posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the messages are in the *Messages* buffer. You can go to it with `C-x b *Messages*` or simply with a left-click on the minibuffer.

Comment: To examine `*Messages*`, you can also use `C-h e`.

Comment: That messages are really in the `*Message*` buffer. But I can't see how dumping message to `*Message*` buffer can be called `ALERT`? Before I expect it is something like `notification`.